# Are there any Keryx offline repository manager alternatives for NetBSD?

Tags: package-management, repository, bsd

I want to install Xfce offline on another computer but I don't know. I searched in internet and found Keryx offline repository manager for Debian-based package
management but not NetBSD. I want to know are there any Keryx offline repository manager alternatives for NetBSD?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/ for what the range of "Keryx alternatives" extends to in this question and how much leeway this gives for answers.

Answer (score 0):

In case FreeBSD you can create repositories with `pkg`'s `repo` subcommand ([man pkg-repo](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-repo&sektion=8&n=1)) if you've a  directory with packages (many `*.txz`). You can use this repository by creating `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/own_repo.conf`:

```
own_repo: {
  url:"file:///path/to/yourpkg/",
  mirror_type:NONE,
  enabled:yes
}
```

Maybe it's worth to check [poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html) to create your own packages from ports: it's automated build system to create package repositories.

Comment: The "portable" (to APT and APT) and "cross-platform" (supporting Debian *and* Ubuntu) tool that the questioner is mentioning does the equivalent of `pkg fetch --dependencies --output` (with a user interface for selecting the packages) to a removable storage device on the first system with the Internet connection and then installing from that on the second system with no such connectivity.  You might want to write an answer that does that.